# How to get transaction id of an order in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.4

How to get transaction id of order in Magento 2?

Comment: do you have any code that you have tried?

Comment: I have tried this 
`$transactionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Payment\Transaction\CollectionFactory');
       
$transactions = $transactionFactory->create()->addOrderIdFilter($_order->getId());
print_r($transactions->getItems());`

but this is not working

Comment: payment transaction id or order id?

Comment: I want payment transaction id

Comment: You shouldn't use objectManager directly in your code

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

Try to inject `Magento\Sales\Api\Data\TransactionSearchResultInterfaceFactory` into your constructor:

```
protected $transactions;

public function __constructor(
  \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\TransactionSearchResultInterfaceFactory $transactions,
  ......
)
{
  $this->transactions = $transactions;
}
```

In your method:

```
$transactions = $this->transactions->create()->addOrderIdFilter($orderId);
$transactions->getItems();
```

If `Magento\Sales\Api\Data\TransactionSearchResultInterfaceFactory` doesn't work, try to use `\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Payment\Transaction\CollectionFactory`. I'm not test yet both of them.

Comment: This is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
class MyClass
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\TransactionRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $repository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    private $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * MyClass constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\TransactionRepositoryInterface $repository
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder      $searchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\TransactionRepositoryInterface $repository,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
    ) {
        $this->repository            = $repository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\TransactionInterface[]
     */
    public function getTransactionByOrderId($id)
    {
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('order_id', $id);
        $list = $this->repository->getList(
            $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create()
        );

        return $list->getItems();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\TransactionSearchResultInterface for transaction Id.

```
$transaction = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\TransactionSearchResultInterfaceFactory')->create()->addOrderIdFilter($block->getOrderId())->getFirstItem();

$transactionId = $transaction->getData('txn_id');
```

The $transactionId is your required transaction Id.