# magento 2 sales order grid add payment transaction column

Tags: admin, sales-order, magento2.3, order-grid, custom-column-grid

How to add Payment transaction column to sales order grid in admin?

Can you please help me step by step?

Regards
Hiren Shah

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean payment method column? If so, if you go to Sales -> Orders, you will see a gear icon with the word "columns" next to it. If you click on it it opens a drop down with various column options. Just select the payment method column and it will show up in the Orders grid.

Comment: No Isoled, I want to add Transaction ID `61739749182` in order grid.

Comment: Ah. If so you could have a look at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/267408/how-to-get-transaction-id-of-an-order-in-magento-2 and combine the solution with Webkul's blog add-custom-columns-to-order-grid-in-admin-magento-2

Answer (score 0):

you need to create custom module and add `sales_order_grid.xml` in  `[Magento_Root]\app\code\[You Module Name]\view\adminhtml\ui_component`.

add new column in `columns` like `Transaction ID`. you need to override `Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection` model and use join query for `sales_payment_transaction` table.

Here some links will help you

[magento2 how to override model file?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160041/magento2-how-to-override-model-file)

[Magento 2 How to Add a New Column to Orders Grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134754/magento-2-how-to-add-a-new-column-to-orders-grid)

May be it will help you.